# When using ffplay, how to eliminate milliseconds from timestamp display in the video-filter

Tags: ffmpeg, timestamp, drawtext, ffplay

So when specifying a video-filter to display current video-time in 'hms' layout, the filter appends a millisecond value after the seconds-field.
I want to eliminate the milliseconds portion.

So far, my invoked cmd looks like:

```
ffplay myfile.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text='%{pts \: hms}':fontsize=20:fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=black"
```

i.e. instead of:    00:00:01.001   I want just   00:00:01 to display.

[One might have thought that there would exist an 'hmsm' for the former,
and that 'hms' would be the latter, but it just doesn't work that way.] (sigh)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Text-expansion):

> `hms` stands for a formatted *[-]HH:MM:SS.mmm* timestamp with millisecond accuracy.

And there's no way to customize this timestamp format. At least not for the `hms` format.
The same documentation:

> If the format is set to `localtime` or `gmtime`, a third argument may be supplied: a strftime() format string. By default, *YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS* format will be used.

So `text='%{pts\:gmtime}'` without any additional arguments puts out `1970-01-01 00:00:00` ([Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)).

To have it put out `00:00:00` set the 2nd argument to `0` and the 3rd to `%H:%M:%S`.

As the `pts` function can take up to 3 arguments, make sure you escape the colons twice on Windows and three times on Unix to prevent `%M` and `%S` from being interpreted as a possible 4th or 5th argument.

**Windows:**

```
ffplay -vf "drawtext=text='%{pts\:gmtime\:0\:%H\\\:%M\\\:%S}':x=1:y=1:fontsize=20:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black:boxborderw=2" myfile.mp4
```

**Unix:**

```
ffplay -vf "drawtext=text='%{pts\:gmtime\:0\:%H\\\\\:%M\\\\\:%S}':x=1:y=1:fontsize=20:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black:boxborderw=2" myfile.mp4
```

Compared to your initial command I've also added `:x=1:y=1` and `:boxborderw=2`. It adds a small border around the text and positions the text nicely centered.
It's a matter of taste of course. You can remove it if you don't like it.

Comment: Thx for all your info Reino.  Unfortunately, that doesn't resolve my issue. (That said, tho, you can have the bounty...if I can find the button where I grant it to you).  I've concluded that what I'm trying to do, just isn't possible.  (Those 'gmtime' examples aren't applicable to me, as I am not trying to display any of those 'time-of-day' related items, but rather the 'timestamp' object that is the elapsed time value of a video...i.e. the current-position (before the duration-time occurs).

Comment: @Dave `text='%{pts\:gmtime\:0\:%H\\\:%M\\\:%S}'` should give you exactly that; the current elapsed time formated as `HH:MM:SS`. Or do I not understand what you're actually looking for?